# How to suppress the Visual Studio 2010 app has triggered a breakpoint prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

I'm migrating a large project from VC++ 6.0 to Visual C++ 2010 (a 32-bit app on WinXP x64).  I use a special BREAK macro that eventually resolves to _asm { int 3 }.  In VC++ 6.0, this will simply stop the debugger just like a manual breakpoint (F9) would.  In VC++ 2010 I get a prompt that says **"myapp.exe has triggered a breakpoint"** and then prompts me to **Break** or **Continue**.

**Is there any way to suppress this prompt?**  I've spent a few hours trying to find a solution to no avail.  This prompt has no added value and really slows me down.

Any help would be most appreciated!  Thanks much!

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When that happens it means an unhandled exception occurred that could not or was not resolved by any calling code. I think this is a safety feature of the debugger designed to make these errors more visible.

If you want to break "just like a breakpoint". Why not just use a breakpoint?

Comment: I do use breakpoints dynamically, but they are unreliable with regards to location when doing development on multiple systems.  A change in the code on one system will cause breakpoints to be mis-aligned on another system.  I have one project that has over half a million lines of code.  It's hard to trust that all the breakpoints are where they should be.

Comment: Also, this feature worked as I needed it to in VC++ 6.0.  Is there any way to retain that same behavior?

Comment: @DouglasHolt No idea. I'd recommend looking at the documentation for VS2010 since the VC++ 6.0 is (now) six versions old. The feature may have been removed.